# C++11 std::stoi silently fails when base not in [2,36] (GCC)

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, std

I'm using GCC 4.9.0 on Linux.  Here's my test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  size_t pos = 42;
  cout << "result: " << stoi(argv[1], &pos, atoi(argv[2])) << '\n';
  cout << "consumed: " << pos << '\n';
}
```

Here's an expected result:

```
$ ./a.out 100 2
result: 4
consumed: 3
```

That is, it parsed "100" in base 2 as the number 4 and consumed all 3 characters.

We can do similar up to base 36:

```
 $ ./a.out 100 36
result: 1296
consumed: 3
```

But what about larger bases?

```
$ ./a.out 100 37
result: 0
consumed: 18446744073707449552
```

What's this?  The `pos` is supposed to be an index where it stopped parsing.  Here it's close to `std::string::npos` but not quite (off by a few million).  And if I compile without optimization then `pos` is `18446744073703251929` instead, so it looks like uninitialized garbage, despite that I did initialize it (to 42).  And indeed, valgrind complains:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
  at 0x400F11: int __gnu_cxx::__stoa<long, int, char, int>(...) (in a.out)
  by 0x400EC7: std::stoi(std::string const&, unsigned long*, int) (in a.out)
```

So that's interesting.  Also, the documentation of `std::stoi` says it throws std::invalid_argument if no conversion could be performed.  Clearly in this case it didn't perform any conversion, and it returned garbage in `pos`, and there was no exception thrown.

Similar bad things happen if `base` is 1 or negative.

Is this a bug in the GCC implementation, a bug in the standard, or just something we have to learn to live with?  I thought one of the goals of `stoi()` vs `atoi()` was better error detection, but it seems not to check `base` at all.

---

Edit: here's a C version of the same program which also prints errno:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char* pos = (char*)42;
  printf("result: %ld\n", strtol(argv[1], &pos, atoi(argv[2])));
  printf("consumed: %lu (%p)\n", pos - argv[1], pos);
  perror("errno");
  return 0;
}
```

When it works, it does the same thing as before.  When it fails, it's a lot more clear:

```
$ ./a.out 100 37
result: 0
consumed: 18446603340345143502 (0x2a)
errno: Invalid argument
```

Now we see why `pos` in the C++ version was a "garbage" value: it was because `strtol()` left `endptr` unchanged, and the C++ wrapper erroneously subtracts the input string starting address from that.

In the C version we also see that `errno` is set to `EINVAL` to indicate the error.  The documentation on my system says this will happen when `base` is invalid, but also says it's not specified by C99.  If we print `errno` in the C++ version we can also detect this error (but it's not standard in C99 and it sure isn't specified by C++11).

Comment: From cpp ref:
Exceptions:
If no conversion could be performed, an invalid_argument exception is thrown.
If the value read is out of the range of representable values by an int, an out_of_range exception is thrown.

An invalid idx causes undefined behavior.

I don't think they implemented better error handling for base larger than 36, simply because there is not enough ASCII signs to use larger bases than 36.

Comment: Did you check the source code ? It's quite intriguing indeed.

Comment: @cerkiewny Would it be interesting to test with `std::wstring` ? There must be a way to perform conversion from larger base than 36. Although it would not explain why this fails silently.

Comment: @Unda I agree the failing silently thing is worrying...

Comment: Note that C++11 defines what `stoi` should do in terms of calls to `strtol`. The C99 standard, in turn, does *not* define what happens when base is not 0 nor between 2 and 36 (some implementations set EINVAL, some don't). And anyhow, `__stoa` (called by `std::stoi`, passing `std::strtol`) doesn't check for EINVAL either: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++/api/a01578_source.html . Can you try with a C pure testcase? I think you've spotted a bug.

Comment: It is unclear what remedy you are looking for.  The C language doesn't have E_PEBKAC, it is assumed.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not using C, I'm using C++.  And the references I've found say an exception is thrown "if no conversion could be performed."  But I've found a case where no conversion is performed yet no exception is thrown.  Not to mention the part where the `pos` is filled with garbage (I would expect `pos` to be zero or unchanged).

Comment: @peppe: I've added a C version of the same program, with some interesting results.

Comment: I like how the C++ program you showed us cannot possibly produce the output you showed us underneath it.

Comment: @Unda: I have now checked the source code from GCC 4.9.0.  In it, `__stoa()` sets `errno = 0` and calls `strtol()` via function pointer.  It then checks if `endptr == str` to see if anything was parsed, but endptr is unchanged by `strtol()` if `base` was invalid.  It never initialized `endptr` itself, so it's garbage, therefore `__stoa()` compares against garbage with indeterminate results (but probably the test fails so it does not throw).  Finally it checks for `errno == ERANGE` which doesn't apply then does the erroneous assignment to `pos`.  Looks like bugs in the implementation to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're right, sorry about that I missed out some extra words in the output statements which I added for clarity.  I'll fix the code.  It doesn't change the test results though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `[C++11: 21.5/3]:` Throws: invalid_argument if `strtol`, `strtoul`, `strtoll`, or `strtoull` reports that no conversion could be performed. *[..]*
>
> `[C99: 7.20.1.4/5]:`  If the subject sequence has the expected form and the value of `base` is zero, the sequence of characters starting with the ﬁrst digit is interpreted as an integer constant according to the rules of 6.4.4.1. If the subject sequence has the expected form and the value of `base` is between 2 and 36, it is used as the base for conversion, ascribing to each letter its value as given above. *[..]*

No semantics are specified in C99 for the case when `base` is *not* zero or between 2 and 36, so the result is undefined. This does not necessarily satisfy the excerpt from `[C++11: 21.5/3]`.

In short, this is UB; you'd expect an exception only when the base is valid but the input value is inconvertible in that base. *This is a bug in neither GCC nor the standard.*

Comment: Well, it sounds like a bug in the C Standard to me: it should specify precisely what happens when `base` is not valid. Not specifying it is quite lazy. (Yes, I do understand that at this point there are tons of incompatible implementations, and part of the reason is precisely because the Standard never cared about clarifying that.)

Comment: You may be right, but it's tragic that GCC produces undefined behavior when it would be so trivial to produce an intuitive, implementation-defined behavior of throwing when the base is invalid.  All it would take is for their `__stoa()` to initialize the `endptr` to the input string, and then magically `invalid_argument` would be thrown in that case.  This seems like a case where C fell short by not specifying what happens when `base` is invalid, then common implementations (GCC, Clang) specified it (EINVAL, as one would expect).  Then C++ left it unspecified again, but this time GCC left it.

Comment: @peppe: Are you essentially stating that the standard is buggy if it does not "bother" to specify semantics for a precondition failure? Sorry, but no. That's not how the world works. It shouldn't even be how your _own_ code works!!

Comment: Well, okay, that said, in this particular instance I might have expected better.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: exactly that. Checking this particular precondition is trivial and one could've expected a better error handling (hence my "lazy"). :)

Comment: @peppe: It's not "laziness"; it's not performing condition checks that don't necessarily _need_ to be performed. Same reason `std::vector::operator[]` does not perform bounds checking. The idea is that you can always add this check yourself, but you could not take it away if the standard library did it for you, even if you knew your input was good (which, face it, is true basically all of the time — at least in release builds). Hence, "precondition". The only reason I feel slightly differently here is that this function already needs to branch on `base` for the zero case.

Comment: Come on, it's not evenly remotely compareable to `operator[]`. It's not inline. It's not O(1). The actual code that gets run is difficult to estimate. It has a loop and some integer math in it, including divisions and modulos. Not standardising the outcome of such a basic check (which notably is already being done by glibc and BSD's libc, and which you need to do anyhow for the `base == 0` case), if not lazy, it is pretty close to being lazy.

Comment: @peppe: Yes, and I said I agree with you in this case. However, as it stands, it is not a bug _per se_.